# Well formed formula in predicate logic

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Considering the following definition of well formed formula (wff) in predicate logic:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula#Predicate_logic

is $\exists x \exists x \varphi(x)$ a wff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

If we apply the definition, if $\varphi(x)$ is a wff, then $\exists x \varphi(x)$ is a wff.

And thus, being $\exists x \varphi(x)$ a wff, also $\exists x \exists x \varphi(x)$ is a wff.

Comment: I think that $\exists x \exists x \varphi(x)$ is the same as $ \exists x \varphi(x)$ but if we have $\forall x \exists x \varphi(x)$ what does it mean?
 Maybe only $\exists x \varphi(x)$?

Comment: @asv - correct. In $\exists x \varphi(x)$ we have **no** free occurrences of $x$. Thus, if we put new quantifiers "on top", the meaning of the formula does not change; i.e. $\exists x \exists x \varphi(x) \equiv \forall x \exists x \varphi(x) \equiv \exists x \varphi(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.